# Differential operator commuting with Euclidean transformations

Tags: differential-operators

Why is it true that a differential operator $S$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ commuting with translations and rotations must be of the form

$$S = \sum a_j \Delta^j $$

where the $a_j$ are constant coefficients ?

Comment: Related?: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/363320/252672 , https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2765037/252672 , https://math.stackexchange.com/q/49521/252672